# Decrypt AES in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, aes

I am encrypting a text with AES256 in swift language and outputting it as hex. I want to decrypt this code I received with JS, but I could not reach the result. I tried the CryptoJS library but still couldn't get the result I wanted. All I want is the js code that will give me the decoded version when I enter the IV, password and ciphertext.

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");

var key = "";
const iv =  "";
const token = "";


function decrypt(token, iv, key) {
    const decrypter = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
    let decrypted = decrypter.update(token, "hex", "utf8");
    decrypted += decrypter.final("utf8");
    return  decrypted
}

console.log(decrypt(token, iv, key));
```

With the Node.js code above, I achieve what I want, but I want to do it with normal JS code, not using node. I don't want to mess with the server. I would be very happy if you help.

EDIT:
I am using CryptoSwift library in Swift language.

```
func encryption(uuid: String, token: String) -> String {
    do {
        let aes = try AES(key: String(uuid.prefix(32)), iv: String(uuid.prefix(16)))
        
        let ciphertext = try aes.encrypt(Array(token.utf8))
        let encrypttext = ciphertext.toHexString()
        return encrypttext
    }
    catch {
        return "error"
    }
}
```

I tried to do something with CryptoJS with the codes from the site below, but it didn't work like the codes in Node.js.

- https://embed.plnkr.co/0VPU1zmmWC5wmTKPKnhg/

EDIT2:

- I've been trying different things but couldn't quite figure it out. I get an error when I add PBKDF2. I don't fully understand the problem.

```js
var password = "6268890F-9B58-484C-8CDC-34F9C6A9";
var iv = "6268890F-9B58-48";
var cipher = "79a247e48ac27ed33ca3f1919067fa64";

/*
var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, {
      keySize: 32
    });
*/

  var dec= CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(cipher);
  const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
  ciphertext: dec 
},
   password, {
     iv: iv,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, 
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
      });

      console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/pbkdf2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Modern browsers have the `window.crypto.subtle` APIs that also support AES: https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#aes-ctr

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm  posting a new edit. @Topaco

Comment: @m90 Thanks for your answer. I looked what you said but I couldn't find any information on decrypting password and hex in AES-CBC - decrypt section.

Comment: I added CryptoJS codes. I am currently getting a null value. When I add PBKDF2 as it is, I get an error. @Topaco

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm happy to finally finish the JS side and return to Swift. By the way, I want to ask something. I don't understand why we changed the iv and password to UTF8, can you tell me? If you write this answer as a separate answer, I will approve your answer. If you do not want to write, I will share the final version. @Topaco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*CryptoJS* uses `WordArray`s, so that key, IV and ciphertext have to be converted accordingly. For this purpose the appropriate encoders have to be applied. Furthermore `decrypt()` expects the ciphertext as `CipherParams` object.

This results in the following possible *CryptoJS* implementation:

```js
var ciphertext = "79a247e48ac27ed33ca3f1919067fa64";
var key = "6268890F-9B58-484C-8CDC-34F9C6A9";
var iv = "6268890F-9B58-48";

var ciphertextWA = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ciphertext);
var keyWA = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
var ivWA = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);
var ciphertextCP = { ciphertext: ciphertextWA };

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    ciphertextCP,
    keyWA, 
    { iv: ivWA }
);

console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)); // Apple
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

which is functionally identical to the posted NodeJS code that also successfully decrypts the test data.

---

Regarding the question asked in the comment about the encodings:
In general, the decryption side must have knowledge of the encodings used for encryption. However, in this case the encodings can be derived from the posted NodeJS code:

- For decryption, the input encoding of the ciphertext is specified as `'hex'`, see [`decipher.update()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_decipher_update_data_inputencoding_outputencoding).
- `key` and `iv` are defined as strings which are UTF-8 encoded, see [`crypto.createDecipheriv()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options).

Also, the data used is consistent with these conclusions.

---

Note that for security reasons a static IV may not be used. Instead, a random IV must be generated for each encryption.
Also, no password may be applied as key, even if it has the right length. If a password is to be used, a key derivation is necessary, e.g. with PBKDF2.
For test purposes, the data is of course enough.